# Pandas: GroupdBy until next row has diferent value

Tags: python, database, pandas, data-science

Getting into Pandas since last week and using chat database for practice.

I'm stuck trying to organize the data into patterns and responses.

This is what I have:

```
    Name    Content
0   patterns    Hi...
1   patterns    Yeaah
2   patterns    
3   patterns    Wellcome!!!
4   patterns    
5   patterns     remember what we've said...
6   responses   where are you?
7   patterns    here
8   patterns    I'll be there...
9   responses   Next to Thyssen
10  responses   eh?
```

What I'm trying to figure out.

Group all patterns or responses that are together into one row. And their 'Content' separated by commas. Tried a lot of ways. This is the one that I think looks more how it should be. But still not good :(

```
for row in df.head().itertuples():
if df['Name' == 'patterns']:
    df_first = df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: "{%s}" % ', '.join(x)).shift('response')
return df
df
```

The result should be like this:

```
    Name    Content
0   patterns    Hi..., Yeaah, , Wellcome!!!, ,  remember what we've said...
6   responses   where are you?
7   patterns    here, I'll be there...
10  responses   Next to Thyssen, eh?
```

Any suggestion how could I achieve this?

Appreciate your time!

Comment: `df.groupby(['Name',df['Name'].ne(df['Name'].shift()).cumsum()],sort=False)['Content'].agg(','.join).droplevel(1).reset_index()`

Comment: Woww that was fast! One day would like to be so clever as you guys are! Keep rocking!